# Regarding storing in binary and displaying its decimal

Tags: c++, binary

Nothing is displayed when I run the following. How should I correct it?

Compiler: g++

My intent: To store the value in binary/hexadecimal/octal and display is decimal equivalent

```
int main()
{

  unsigned char c = 0b00001111;
  cout << c << endl;

}
```

Comment: Why are you storing it in a `char` variable?

Comment: Which compiler?  `0b00001111` is an illegal token according to the standard.

Comment: @JamesKanze: `0b` is a gcc extension to represent binary literals.

Comment: @JamesKanze It works, check answer below

Comment: @alk I realized that it was an extension, although I didn't know for which compiler.  That's why I asked.

Comment: @codeymodey It may work with some compilers.  It won't work with all.  (It doesn't work with VC++, and it generates a warning with the options I usually use with g++: `-std=c++11 -pendantic`.)

Comment: Yes, you are right, that is the reason I wrote compiler with the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0b00001111` equals `15` and is a non-printable character.

Try `0b1000001` which equals `65` and should print an `A`.

To get the `15` do:

```
cout << (int) c << endl;
```

For printable ASCII codes please see her: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters